# Buttons in Viewpager does not update

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager

Hi I'm still very new to android. What I'm trying to do is, i have pictures in my viewPager with a button on top. If you press a button, a sound will be played. but when i swipe to the next page, and if i press the button again, it should play the new sound according to the new pic. following is my code. But it plays the old sound from the previous pic. It does not update with the new position value. Please do help me to troubleshoot.

```
OnPageChangeListener player;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Set title for the ViewPager
    //setTitle("ViewPager");
    // Get the view from view_pager.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);
    final ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
    //

    //
    // Retrieve data from MainActivity on item click event
    Intent p = getIntent();
    position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");

    ImageAdapterchap1 imageAdapter = new ImageAdapterchap1(this);
    List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

    // Retrieve all the images
    for (int i = 0; i < imageAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[i]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        images.add(imageView);


    // Set the images into ViewPager
    ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);

    viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);

    // Show images following the position
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

   final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_alarm);
    final MediaPlayer cpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.car_ignition);
    final MediaPlayer fpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.helicopter);
    final MediaPlayer ffButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.motorcycle);


    Button info=(Button) findViewById(R.id.audio);
    info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (viewpager.getCurrentItem()) {
        case 0:
            mpButtonClick.start();

            // do something
            break;
        case 1:
            cpButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 2:
            fpButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 3:
            ffButtonClick.start();
            // do something
            break;
        case 4:
            // do something
            break;
        }
    }

    });

    OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
        {

        ffButtonClick.stop();
        mpButtonClick.stop();
        cpButtonClick.stop();
        fpButtonClick.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };


    }


    } 



public void destroyItem( View pager, int position, Object view )
{
    ((ViewPager)pager).removeView( (View)view );
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `position` variable you are using isn't getting updated anywhere. If you want to know the current item position in the ViewPager you should use:

```
viewpager.getCurrentItem();
```

Or update the `position` variable using an `OnPageChangeListener` and the `viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(listener)` method.

**EDIT:**

The `viewpager.getCurrentItem()` should be used as the parameter of the switch:

```
switch(viewpager.getCurrentItem()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I'm still facing the same problem. i tried using viewpager.getCurrentItem(); but the same problem surfaces. I'm not sure how to use page change listener. Please do help me out.

Comment: You should use the previous method on the switch: `switch(viewpager.getCurrentItem()){`

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working perfectly. Just one more question, how do i make the sound stop if i swipe to the next page. Again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's nice to see I was helpful. To stop the music you will need to implement the `OnPageChangeListener` I told you before. To do that, you should call `viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){...});` and on the `onPageSelected(int position){...}` method call `.stop()` on all the MediaPlayer objects you instantiated.

Comment: And another trouble I'm facing is that, as i swipe to the next image, and then change it horizontally, the app gets really slow and sometime, hangs. Is there a way to improve this.?

Comment: It probably happens because you are having memory leaks. Some object (big ones, like Bitmaps) are still attached to the old activity and it won't die. Anyway, I think you should open another question in order to receive a better answer.

Comment: Sure will do. Thank you so much. But for the OnPageChangeListner, i put it after the 'case', but it seems not to be working. Here is the code.

Comment: OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
        {

            
            public void onPageSelected(int arg1)
            {
             
            ffButtonClick.stop();
            mpButtonClick.stop();
            cpButtonClick.stop();
            fpButtonClick.stop();
            }

            
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
            {
            }

         
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
            {
            }
        };

Comment: Are you assigning it to the `viewpager` object with `viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player)`?

Comment: Oh no. Im not. im still not sure how to use PageChanger. So to which object should i assigned it to?

Comment: The previous line (`viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);`) should work. Just copy it below the declaration of the `player`object and it should assing it as the OnPageChangeListener of the `viewpager`.

Comment: Under my public class, i initialize player as private static final OnPageChangeListener player = null;   And inside OnCreate i insert  viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(player); but it says the viewpager cannot be resolved.

Comment: Why static? Or null? If you initialize it as an instance object you can assign it to `viewpager`whenever you want using the line I gave you. Anyway, the simplest way to do it is just initialize it at the end of the `onCreate` method and assign it to the `viewpager` on the next line.

Comment: Im still unable to get it right. Not sure where is the problem. I will upload my latest code here, as in modify the above question.

Comment: You are initializing `player` at the end of your onCreate method but assigning it at the beginning, when it still does not exist. Assign it  right after initializing it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works now, but after sliding to the next page, the buttton does not work anymore. when pressed, no sound comes out.

Comment: Actually, it seems like `.stop()` on the MediaPlayer objects unloads the audio to play, so instead of stopping every MediaPlayer you should use `nameOfPlayer.pause(); nameOfPlayer.seekTo(0);`

Comment: I have tried .pause(); but that just pauses the sound. when i swipe to the next page, it stops, but other sounds dont play. when im back to the original page, it continues the sound back.

Comment: if i tried using .seekTo(0), when i swipe, the previous sound restarts, and when i press the button, the sound for that image will play along with the previous sound.

Comment: I meant `.pause()` and right after that `.seekTo(0)`. That way the sound will stop and it will come back to the beginning.

Comment: I have tried the following code, but it just pauses the current sound, but when i swipe to the following page, there is no sound and when i press the button, there is no sound